# Use Spring Security with Oracle & Grails

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy, spring-security

I would like to ask which exactly plugin should I use to achievie following functionality:

1. User send HTTP post contains JSON with username & password data (to grails web service)
2. Ask Oracle DB with these data and receive true or false
3. If true generate Token and keep somewhere information about user&token (could be domain class)
4. Check every other request if it contains valid token and allow user to custom my webservice.

So far, I tried 2 plugins: spring-security-rest & spring-security-core. Both worked fine (spring security rest by Alvaro Sanchez offer almost all functionality listed above), but both force on me 2 domain classes : User and Role (currently i dont want store this kind of data there).

Do You have some solutions? Or should I do this all functionality by myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Security plugin does not force you to store user and role data in `User` and `Role` domain classes. It doesn't even force you to store them in the database at all. You can get this data from anywhere (a web service, memory, a text file, etc.) but if you're not storing it in domain classes you'll need to provide a custom `UserDetailsService` bean. This is a pretty simple exercise, which is [explained in the plugin's docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html).

Comment: Should I do something else? When in myUserDetailsService I am returning userDetails it seems that it checks that this data is correct. 2014-12-01 11:31:59,910 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value